# Xcode project not opening in Xcode 8 - cannot be parsed

Tags: ios, xcode, parsing

After many months i've come back to trying to build my app. Last time i tried i was using Xcode 7 and now i have Xcode 8.

When i have clicked on the .xcodeproj file sometimes nothing happens at all, its like Xcode has completely ignored me. Sometime i get a cannot be parsed warning.

I have read up on here and some say editing the .pbxproj file. However, when i try and open ANY file in my project with the Text Editor on Mac the file is just empty.

I have a .swift file saved which has some code in i wrote before and would like to use but i just cannot open it, either in Xcode or in any text editor.

any ideas anyone please?

Comment: Your pbxproj file being empty would explain why you can't open the project. So where is your backup? (At home, I have two backups, so there is a git repo on three drives, plus BitBucket, so I can get back any pbxproj file that I ever had from four different places)

Comment: Yes I have a copy but it's the same in both. Before I stopped working on the app I also created a archive of the app using Xcode and I have that file as well but don't know what to do with it because there is no xcodeproj file in it.